# How to import complex dict into pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data extracted from an XML file:

```
d = {
    'test1': {
        0: {'a': {'min': 1, 'mid': 12, 'max': 13},
            'b': {'min': 2, 'mid': 22, 'max': 23}},
        3: {'a': {'min': 3, 'mid': 32, 'max': 33},
            'b': {'min': 4, 'mid': 42, 'max': 43}},
        8: {'a': {'min': 5, 'mid': 52, 'max': 53},
            'b': {'min': 6, 'mid': 62, 'max': 63}},            
    },
    'test2': {
        0: {'a': {'min': 9, 'mid': 12, 'max': 13},
            'b': {'min': 8, 'mid': 22, 'max': 23}},
        3: {'a': {'min': 7, 'mid': 32, 'max': 33},
            'b': {'min': 6, 'mid': 42, 'max': 43}},
        8: {'a': {'min': 5, 'mid': 52, 'max': 53},
            'b': {'min': 4, 'mid': 62, 'max': 63}},           
    },
}
```

And I imported it with:

```
ds = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

I would like to name my columns then start browsing my data.

The columns are: `['Tests', 'Id', 'Item']`

For example I would like to get all the `mid` value for all Tests, any Item and any Id. So I naively wrote:

```
ds[:,:,:,'min']
```

But obviously it doesn't work.

Also I am afraid the dataframe is not represented like it supposed to. What to do to make it like this?

```
+-------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
|       |    |      | min | mid | max |
+-------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| Tests | Id | Item |     |     |     |
+-------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
|       | 0  |  a   |  1  | 12  | 13  |
|       |    |  b   |  2  | 22  | 23  |
+ test1 +----+------+-----+-----+-----+
|       | 1  |  a   |  3  | 32  | 33  |
|       |    |  b   |  4  | 42  | 43  |
+-------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
|       | 0  |  a   |  9  | 12  | 13  |
|       |    |  b   |  8  | 22  | 23  |
+ test2 +----+------+-----+-----+-----+
|       | 1  |  a   |  7  | 32  | 33  |
|       |    |  b   |  6  | 42  | 43  |
+-------+----+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do some manual transformation with `stack` after reading them in (it may be difficult to get this done in one single step since in general the dictionary can be nested as deep as it can):

```
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
   .stack().apply(pd.Series)
   .stack().apply(pd.Series)
   .rename_axis(("Tests", "Id", "Item")))
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error for `.rename_axis`: tuple object is not callable. Is that normal?

Comment: It's not normal. Maybe you have some parenthesis misplaced? It works fine for your sample data.

Comment: Can you have a look at this? https://gist.github.com/nowox/1d0165221ac17a6de071f51c5428b599

Comment: I tried what you have posted. It works. What python and pandas version are you using? And also maybe try a new python session in case you have shadowed something in the current one.

Comment: What you want to achieve from that? If all rows with index of 8, try `ds.loc[(slice(None), 8, slice(None)), :]`.